# Count records by users in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am trying to display the records that a user has in a table relation.

I have the loan_applications table that is related to the users table.

In my view I count this way `{!! $ loanapplications-> count () !!}` and tell me all the records.

But I need to count the records by users, I tried using the `Auth :: user ()` method, but at the moment I can not do it.

This is the relationship of the tables in the migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateLoanApplicationsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('loan_applications', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('order',16)->unique();
            $table->string('loan_quantity');
            $table->string('loan_interests');
            $table->string('loan_type');
            $table->string('loan_time');
            $table->string('status');
            $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();            
            $table->foreign('client_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('clients')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();            
            $table->foreign('user_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('users')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('comments')->nullable();            
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('loan_applications');
    }
}
```

This is my model:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\LoanApplication;
use App\Client;
use App\Loans;
use DB;

class LoansController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $data = Loans::order($request->get('criteria'))->orderBy('id','ASC')->paginate(8);

        $loanapplications = DB::table('loan_applications')->get();

        $pendings = DB::table('loan_applications')->where('status', '=', '0')->get();

        $approved = DB::table('loan_applications')->where('status', '=', '1')->get();

        $declined = DB::table('loan_applications')->where('status', '=', '2')->get();

        //dd($data);

        return view('loans.index',compact('data', 'loanapplications', 'pendings', 'approved', 'declined'))
            ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create($id)
    {
        $data = DB::table('loan_applications')->find($id);

        dd($data);

        return view('loans.create',compact('data'));
    }
}
```

This is my show method in my controller:

```
public function show($id)
{       

    $data = LoanApplication::find($id);

    $clients = DB::table('clients')->find($id);

    //$users = User::find($id);

    $users = App\User::withCount('loan_applications')->find($id);

    $loanapplications = DB::table('loan_applications')->get();

    $pendings = DB::table('loan_applications')->where('status', '=', '0')->get();

    $approved = DB::table('loan_applications')->where('status', '=', '1')->get();

    $declined = DB::table('loan_applications')->where('status', '=', '2')->get();

    //dd($data, $clients, $users);

    return view('loanapplications.show',compact('data', 'clients', 'users', 'loanapplications', 'pendings', 'approved', 'declined'));
}
```

And this is the counter in the element a href

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
    <span class="label label-warning">{!! $loanapplications->count() !!}</span>
</a>
```

Someone who can give me a small orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official documentaiton :

```
$posts = App\Post::withCount('comments')->get();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->comments_count;
}
```

So in your `show` method, you can do something like :

```
$user = App\User::withCount('loan_applications')->find(X /* User ID */);
```

Then return the `$user` to your view and you will get the property `loan_applications_count` on that object.

*This is not based on the Authenticated User in order to allow you to dynamically pass the user as parameter, if you want to do it with the authenticated user, you still can.

**Of course you have to define the `loan_applications` relationship in your `User` model.

[Edit]

You can either retrieve the user ID of the authenticated user by calling `Auth::user()->id`, then pass it to the find method, or access the relationship with `Auth::user()->loan_applications->count`, but I'm not sure about this one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but in theory what I try to do is that the user, see the requests that he has generated, that is why the interest of doing the count with authentication (Auth :: user).

Comment: Returns with FatalErrorException Call to a member function count() on null

Comment: Can you please paste the code ? which one did you used ? Are you authenticated ? Is the relationship correctly set up ?